# Get filenames for results returned from ActivityResultContracts.OpenMultipleDocuments() contract

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fileprovider

In my Android app, I launch a document chooser so the user can import some documents into my app:

```
this.intentlauncherchoosedoc = this.registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.OpenMultipleDocuments(), 
    new ActivityResultCallback<List<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(List<Uri> urilist) {
            for (Uri uri : urilist) {
                String filename = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                createdoc(uri, filename);
            }
        }
    }   
);
```

Unfortunately, when the user choose a document, the uri that comes back looks like this:

> content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=1;doc=encoded=mgMyynWh7Lrq1qW1dradGc60EJWehheCQiS5mYY7a8CF80Ouzro=

Is there any way to get the original filename of the document that was chosen, so that I can save that filename and list it to my user when they are reviewing their imported docs?

Comment: You can try `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri().getName()` to attempt to get a "display name" for the document. This may or may not be a filename, as the content selected by the user may or may not be a file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I read the linked answers you provided when closing this question, and while I understand that it doesn't guarantee a filename being there, there -is- an answer on how to get the filename and I figured it out. I wanted to post it as an answer to my own question, but this got closed too quickly. Querying the metadata via the Content Resolver let's me get access to a filename, if there is one, and that is a reasonable answer... but it's not contained in your linked answers.

Comment: Reading through the docs, I figured out how to get access to the filename by querying for the metadata associated with the uri:

`Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(incominguri, null, null, null, null);

   String filename = null;
   if (cursor != null) {
    int nameindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    filename = cursor.getString(nameindex);
    cursor.close();
   }`

Comment: Note that this is not necessarily a filename, and you will need to guard against data sources that fail to implement `OpenableColumns` support.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of others searching for this, here is sample Kotlin code to open a *single* file and retrieve its name and content. The use of `GetContent()` *guarantees* that the column `DISPLAY_NAME` will be included in the returned metadata.

```kotlin
    private val getFile = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
        requireActivity().contentResolver.apply { 
            query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
                val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                cursor.getString(nameIndex)
            }?.let { fileName ->
                openInputStream(uri)?.use { stream ->
                    presenter.addFile(fileName, stream)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And to link it to a button:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.chooseFile).setOnClickListener {
            getFile.launch("*/*")
        }
    }
```