# MIUI Bug - Intent getting Activity.RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, android-intent, android-11, xiaomi, miui

After updating to Android 11 MIUI 12.5.2 Global `Intent` result is [buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69213690/12204620) and returning `RESULT_CANCELED` when selecting image file. We thought it was part of Android 11 breaking changes but testing it on Android 12 has no issue. Now we are having [issue](https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/253) on same device as well using image cropping library. It seems this only occurs in MIUI with Android 11 and there's currently no clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that works, but is not sustainable, is this:

> Just go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer Option -> Turn on MIUI optimization (enable it)
> Note - If not see the option "Turn on MIUI optimization" then click "Reset to default values" 4-5 times. It will enable the option.

Source: https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker/issues/440#issuecomment-897352982

On my side I noticed that the problem was caused by the `Intent.createChooser`.
So I replaced it with an `ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()` and now it works also on Xiaomi with Android 11 !

`GetMultipleContents()` because I was using `Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`. But otherwise you can use `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()`.

Code: https://github.com/Infomaniak/android-kDrive/pull/891/files